# Issue with Youtube Data API integration

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I wanted to integrate the Youtube Data API in my application. For the same reason, with reference to the following link,
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples  and create my client id and tried running the code.

I am working with Javascript + HTML. While running the code I am getting the following error.

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=AIzaSyARXJSURlAnAm48f3uXok0rB7GrEGb3pLc&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&immediate=true&include_granted_scopes=true&proxy=oauth2relay311121687&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&response_type=token&state=475509781%7C0.2158929842&authuser=0 does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

Can anyone suggest me what went wrong and how can I fix the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to break down your requested URL to the minimum. Maybe there is one GET that conflicts with other configs.

Comment: how can I do that? In which file do I need to do the requested changes

Comment: Give me some of your code, maybe than I can help. If necessary black out your accountdata like password

Comment: My code is from the following link, https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/javascript. I am using (search.html, search.js and auth.js). I did not change anything except my client id in the auth.js

Comment: I need only for search so I am using only corresponding 3 files (search.html, search.js and auth,js). Any suggestions would be highly appreciable